# Anaconda environment for CPU and GPU versions of TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, conda

I want to create two separate environments with TensorFlow in anaconda, one with CPU only support, which is compiled from sources, and one with GPU support using official Tensorflow binaries.

I have set up two environments with conda, using `conda create -n gpu --clone root`. I activate my new environment using `source activate gpu`. However, whenever I install a TensorFlow version using pip, the old environment is affected as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you activating an environment before you install tensorflow?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `conda create -n gpu python=3.6` (or whatever python version you want) instead of `conda create -n gpu` when you create an environment.

---

The idea of conda is to have an isolated environment that it has its own python, pip, etc. To create a new environment with isolated installed program, you need to explicitly declare it, otherwise, it uses the shared program between all environments. You can activate the environments and try `which python` or `which pip` to make sure they have their own version of python and pip.

Answer (score 0):

Conda uses hard links extensively. It's likely that pip is overwriting files that conda has already created, without removing the file first, and thereby affecting files in your other conda environments.

Try adding the `--copy` flag to your `create --clone` command.